# Data truncated while importing from Excel using OLEDB, what are the alternatives?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, office-interop

I have a WPF application where I have functionality to read data from Excel.
I was doing this using OLEDB and it was working great, until I found out there was a 255 limit for columns and the data would be truncated unless data > 255 characters is not present in the first eight rows. Fix for this issue is to update the registry which would mean updating all users' registries. So I don't want to go with that approach.

OLEDB code:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
 DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(ds1);
```

As an alternative, I tried Interop.Excel . However, it seems to be slower that OLEDB. The Excel sheets that were taking 2 seconds to load take about 15 seconds using Interop.Excel.

```
System.Data.DataTable tempTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
tempTable.TableName = "ResultData";
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book = null;
Excel.Range range = null;
try
{
 app.Visible = false;
 app.ScreenUpdating = false;
 app.DisplayAlerts = false;

 book = app.Workbooks.Open(inputFilePath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value
                                              , Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value
                                             , Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value
                                            , Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
  foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in book.Worksheets)
  {
    Logger.LogException("Values for Sheet " + sheet.Index, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString());
    // get a range to work with
    range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
    // get the end of values to the right (will stop at the first empty cell)
    range = range.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight);
    // get the end of values toward the bottom, looking in the last column (will stop at first empty cell)
    range = range.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown);

     // get the address of the bottom, right cell
     string downAddress = range.get_Address(
     false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

      // Get the range, then values from a1
      range = sheet.get_Range("A1", downAddress);
                    object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

      //Get the Column Names 
      for (int k = 0; k < values.GetLength(1); )
      {
         tempTable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(values[1, ++k]).Trim());
      }

      for (int i = 2; i <= values.GetLength(0); i++)//first row contains the column names, so start from the next row.
      {
      System.Data.DataRow dr = tempTable.NewRow();
         for (int j = 1; j <= values.GetLength(1); j++)//columns
        {
           dr[j - 1] = values[i, j];
         }
                        tempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
```

Is there another alternative which is as fast as OLEDB?

The columns and rows are not fixed in the Excel sheet.

Comment: Are you dealing with `xls` files or `xlsx` files?

Comment: You can use ACE which is a Microsoft Office driver.  Oledb comes with windows  while ACE comes with office.  I think you can install ACE without an office license but I have never successfully done it.  You only need to change the connection string.  See www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is xlsx files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response.Here is the final code that I used:
Reference link : http://www.prowareness.com/blog/reading-data-from-excel-document-using-openxml/

```
 public static DataSet ExtractExcelSheetValuesToDataTable(string xlsxFilePath, string sheetName)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsxFilePath, true))
            {
                //Access the main Workbook part, which contains data
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))
                {
                    Sheet ss = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).SingleOrDefault<Sheet>();
                    worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(ss.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
                if (worksheetPart != null)
                {
                    Row lastRow = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().LastOrDefault();
                    Row firstRow = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (firstRow != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Cell c in firstRow.ChildElements)
                        {
                            string value = GetValue(c, stringTablePart);
                            dt.Columns.Add(value);
                        }
                    }
                    if (lastRow != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow.RowIndex; i++)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            bool empty = true;
                            Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().Where(r => i == r.RowIndex).FirstOrDefault();
                            int j = 0;
                            if (row != null)
                            {
                                foreach (Cell c in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                                {
                                    int? colIndex = GetColumnIndex(((DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellType)(c)).CellReference);
                                    if (colIndex > j)
                                    {
                                        dr[j] = "";
                                        j++;
                                    }
                                    //Get cell value
                                    string value = GetValue(c, stringTablePart);
                                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                                    //    empty = false;
                                    dr[j] = value;
                                    j++;
                                    if (j == dt.Columns.Count)
                                        break;
                                }

                                //foreach (Cell c in row.ChildElements)
                                //{
                                //    //Get cell value
                                //    string value = GetValue(c, stringTablePart);
                                //    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                                //    //    empty = false;
                                //    dr[j] = value;
                                //    j++;
                                //    if (j == dt.Columns.Count)
                                //        break;
                                //}
                                //if (empty)
                                //    break;
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            return ds;
        }
        public static string GetValue(Cell cell, SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart)
        {
            if (cell.ChildElements.Count == 0) return null;
            //get cell value
            string value = cell.ElementAt(0).InnerText;//CellValue.InnerText;
            //Look up real value from shared string table
            if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                value = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
            return value;
        }

        private static int? GetColumnIndex(string cellReference)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellReference))
            {
                return null;
            }

            //remove digits
            string columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]", string.Empty);

            int columnNumber = -1;
            int mulitplier = 1;

            //working from the end of the letters take the ASCII code less 64 (so A = 1, B =2...etc)
            //then multiply that number by our multiplier (which starts at 1)
            //multiply our multiplier by 26 as there are 26 letters
            foreach (char c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse())
            {
                columnNumber += mulitplier * ((int)c - 64);

                mulitplier = mulitplier * 26;
            }

            //the result is zero based so return columnnumber + 1 for a 1 based answer
            //this will match Excel's COLUMN function
            return columnNumber;
        }
```

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as accepted, questions with no accepted answers get autopromoted to the front page every few months.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with xlsx files I would recommend switching to the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), it performs much better than OLEDB or the Interop methods of connecting.

However, some people consider the SDK difficult to use so there are [3rd party packages](http://mstum.github.io/Simplexcel/) that will wrap up the SDK into a more friendly interface, but personally I don't find the SDK too hard to do.